# Execute else block from within if block

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript, is there a way to skip to the else block from within the if block?

Here's an example:

```
if (is_valid) {
  some code;

  if (!something_else_is_valid) {
    // Skip to else to handle error;
  }
} else {
  handle_error_here;
}
```

I know I could just move the handle_error functionality to another function but I don't want to do that.

Thanks for your answers/comments!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In JavaScript, is there a way to skip to the else block from within the if block?

No, because the condition is already achieved, therefore it's not possible to go back and enter on `else` condition.

You can use the statement `switch`.  The `break` keyword stops the downstream execution. If `something_else_is_valid` is false, the `break` won't occur, so the `switch` block will reach the `default` case which is the "error case".

```js
function A(is_valid, something_else_is_valid) {
  switch(is_valid) {
    case true: 
      // some code
      if (something_else_is_valid) {
        // do somthing
        break;
      } // else, will reach default case.
    default:
      throw new Error("Wrong!");
      // handle_error_here
  }
}

A(true, false);
```

Answer (score 2):

Never say never: ***Yes*** - and they will hate you doing so, but hey:

```js
var else_ = false
var if_ = true

IF: 
{
 if(if_){
    console.log("entered IF BLOCK")
    var second = false
    if(!second){
      console.log("exits to ELSE BLOCK")
      else_ = true
      break IF;
      console.log("this will not be executed - its skipped")
    }
 }
}
ELSE: {
  if(!else_) break ELSE;
  console.log("entered ELSE BLOCK")
  
}
```

label your blocks accordingly and you can exit an if block into an else block ;)

Answer (score 1):

No, once an `if` is entered, there's no ability to backtrack, though you could recursively call the containing function with `is_valid` of `false`:

```
function doTest(is_valid) {
  if (is_valid) {
    // some code;

    if (!something_else_is_valid) {
      return doTest(false);
    }
  } else {
    // handle_error_here;
  }
}
```

You could use `try/catch` as well (though, ideally, exceptions are exceptional, rather than a control flow construct):

```
try {
  if (!is_valid) {
    throw new Error();
  }
  // some code;
  if (!something_else_is_valid) {
    throw new Error();
  }
} catch(e) {
  // handle_error_here;
}
```

Even better than both *would* be to handle errors in a single function that you can call, but you said you didn't want to do that.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't - you have to combine conditions:

```
if (is_valid && something_else_is_valid) {
    //Some code
} else {
    handle_error_here();
}
```

Comment: I don't want to do that because I need some code to run in the if block before I evaluate `something_else_is_valid`.

Comment: Then you have to nest the `else`.